# css + html: relative percentages? (mediaqueries)

Tags: html, css, youtube, media-queries

hey guys,
weird situation where I don't have a clue how to solve this.

I'm trying to to a responsive website with mediaqueries. Embedded YouTube videos shouls also respond to the layout, therefore I'm trying to set the with of each video to 100% and calculate its height in ratio!

The outcome looks like this:

```
<p class="youtube-vid">
<object width="100%" height="61%">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="61%" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
</p>
```

So originally this video was 500px by 306px when embedding it from youtube.

The problem is this thing might actually work but I don't know where the percentages refer to. Where 100% in width is totally correct and dependant od my layout 61% in height is not correct. 61% is the correct number, however it looks wrong because it's probably 61% of some outer container or something.

Any idea how I could solve this problem. I simply want my videos to be 100% in with (which is correct right now - even when resizing) and the proportional height depending on the original values of the video?

Answer (score 2):

`height` and `width` are calculated separately and independent of the original aspect ratio. Try just setting `height="100%"` and the `width` not at all. I know this works with images to keep the aspect ratio, but I'm not sure it it works with objects, too.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I might use javascript to solve this thingy.